# Base tag breaks script links in Angular HTML5 mode

Tags: angularjs, html, express

**Problem**

After setting a base tag to run Angular 1.x in HTML5 mode, the browser (Chrome) makes requests to the wrong path for scripts when accessing the app by navigating directly to `localhost:3000/resource/id`.

**Details**

I have an Angular 1 app that I have recently set to run in HTML5 mode, like so:

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I have included a base tag in the head of index.html like so:

```
<base href="/">
```

I have set up my express routes so that a request for (for example) `http://localhost:3000/album/38ad87f` will return index.html, like so:

```
    .use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/crate-frontend/app'))

// Playlist endpoints
.use('/api/playlists', playlistRoutes)

// Album endpoints
.use('/api/album', albumRoutes)

// Artist endpoints
.use('/api/artist', artistRoutes)

// Track endpoints
.use('/api/tracks', trackRoutes)

// User endpoints
.use('/api/user', userRoutes)

// Discogs proxy endpoints
.use('/api/discogs', discogsRoutes)

// Youtube proxy endpoints
.use('/api/youtube', youtubeRoutes)

// Search endpoints
.use('/api/search', searchRoutes)

// For serving up crate-frontend/app/index.html
.all('/*', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/crate-frontend/app/index.html' );
})
```

Now, when I go to the home page, and navigate around, everything works fine. BUT if I refresh the page that is not the root OR a copy/paste a URL like `http://localhost:3000/album/38ad87f` into a new window, it breaks. I can see that it receives index.html, but then when the browser requests each of the linked scripts, for example:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

it actually makes a request to `http://localhost:3000/album/app.js`, which returns index.html.

Can someone tell me what I've missed / am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include your ressources with an absolute path and you will be fine for all time.

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb but I am so glad I asked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @marcushaddon glad to help ya.